# Python CTypes _argtypes has no from_params method

Tags: python, ctypes

- I have been tasked with creating a wrapper class in python using
  ctypes. I have been coding and doing research for the past
  couple of weeks, and have a question for anyone willing to
  help. This C code is my best replication of the code that I am working with, so keep in mind that I did not structure it in the way that it is presented!
- I am relatively new to both python and the ctypes library
- Using Python 2.7.2, and GCC 4.4.2 on linux

> Question:
>   When I try to run the following python code, I get this error:
>   File "pydog.py", line 21, in 
>   srclib.log_dog.argtypes = [pug]
>   TypeError: item 1 in *argtypes* has no from_param method

**pydog.py:**

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

 srclib = ctypes.CDLL('/path/DogHouse.so')

 class dog(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("name", ctypes.c_char*10),
        ("color", ctypes.c_char*10)]    

pug = dog("doug", "white")

#- Not sure if I need to define arg and res types -#
srclib.log_dog.argtypes = [pug]
#srclib.log_dog.restype = 

srclib.log_dog(pug)
```

**DogHouse.h:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* opaque handle */
typedef struct __dog_file dogfile;

/* Input data structure */
typedef struct __dog_input{
    const char *name;
    const char *color;
    }dog_input;

/*Logs the dog_input data into the dog_file struct */
dog_file *log_dog(const dog_input *data);
```

**DogHouse.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "DogHouse.h"

struct __dog_file{
    const char *name;
    const char *color;
    };

dog_file *log_dog(const dog_input *data){

        dog_file *df;               
        df->name = data->name;
        df->color = data->color;

        return df;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

}
```

I tried finding the syntax for "from_param", but I couldn't find specifically what I needed (I'm not sure if it is ctypes specific, or standard to the python library.

This is my first question on SO, so if I need to change anything/be more clear let me know! Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Mark pointed out the actual error, but to clarify, `from_param` is a class method called by ctypes to convert a function argument to a ctypes type. When you assign `argtypes` to a function pointer, it needs to reference each type's `from_param` converter. The standard types have implementations of this method that do some basic conversions, such as converting `None` for a pointer type, Python strings for `c_char_p` or `c_wchar_p`, and integers for `c_int`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values in `argtypes` should be types.  `pug` is an instance.  The code as given wouldn't compile, but the following is what I came up with:

**pydog.py**

```
import ctypes

srclib = ctypes.CDLL('DogHouse')

# An opaque class
class dog_file(ctypes.Structure):
   pass

# c_char_p should be used for "const char *"
class dog_input(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("name", ctypes.c_char_p),
        ("color", ctypes.c_char_p)]    

srclib.log_dog.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(dog_input)] # pointer type
srclib.log_dog.restype =  ctypes.POINTER(dog_file) # pointer type to opaque class

# bytes strings used for const char* (Python 3 syntax)
# create instance and pass it to function
pug = dog_input(b'doug',b'white')
print(srclib.log_dog(pug))
```

**DogHouse.h**

```
/* opaque handle */
typedef struct dog_file dog_file;

/* Input data structure */
typedef struct dog_input
{
    const char* name;
    const char* color;
} dog_input;

/*Logs the dog_input data into the dog_file struct */
__declspec(dllexport)
dog_file* log_dog(const dog_input* data);
```

**DogHouse.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "DogHouse.h"

typedef struct dog_file
{
    const char* name;
    const char* color;
} dog_file;

dog_file* log_dog(const dog_input* data)
{
    dog_file* df = malloc(sizeof(dog_file));
    df->name = data->name;
    df->color = data->color;
    return df;
}
```

Note that in the function implemention, the original was returning a local variable.  This version mallocs the memory, but you would need to export another function to free it or have a memory leak.

**Output** (the opaque pointer instance)

```
<__main__.LP_dog_file object at 0x00000000030040C8>
```